# Stretching one of the three svg in width in a block

Tags: html, css, svg

I need to stretching one of the three svg in a block. So, first and last svg must be always 100px width and second svg should be 100px, 200px, 1000px, but they must be closed to each other without between space.

```
 HTML
 <div class="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect class="st0" width="100px"  height="100px"/>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 500 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <rect class="st1" width="500px"  height="100px"/>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect class="st2" width="100px"  height="100px"/>
  </svg>
 </div>
CSS
 svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
 }
 svg rect.st2 {
  fill: red;
 }
 svg rect.st1 {
  fill: green;
  width: 500px;
 }
 svg rect.st0 {
  fill: blue;
 }
 .container {
  display: flex;
 }
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/esf16w9y/244/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the container is flex, you can just add `flex-grow:1;` to the svg you want to grow:

```css
 svg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
 }
 svg rect.st2 {
  fill: red;
 }
 svg rect.st1 {
  fill: green;
 }
 svg rect.st0 {
  fill: blue;
 }
 .container {
  display: flex;
 }
 
 .container svg:nth-child(2) {flex-grow:1;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect class="st0" width="100px"  height="100px"/>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 500 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <rect class="st1" width="500px"  height="100px"/>
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <rect class="st2" width="100px"  height="100px"/>
  </svg>
 </div>
```

If you are wanting set widths of 100, 200 and 1000, then you will need to use media queries and define when you want those widths to be used

Comment: thanks, but if i want center line instead of a rectangle? Will this work?

Comment: Probably not (because you are using `preserveAspectRatio="none"`). If you have additional requirements, then include them in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some alternative static solution i dont know it helps or not but yes you can control individual svg by css.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
svg:nth-child(2) {
  width: 1000px;
}
svg rect.st2 {
  fill: red;
}
svg rect.st1 {
  fill: green;
  width: 2000px;
}
svg rect.st0 {
  fill: blue;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/sahapramesh/bd0s5j49/1/)